# application not working in weblogic

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, weblogic

I deployed an application in WebLogic, after generating the project by deploying it in Tomcat. The project works fine in Tomcat but not in Weblogic.

Lots of errors like:

<--date-->

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101020> <[weblogic.servlet.int
ernal.WebAppServletContext@1f9a403 - appName: 'app-name', name: 'app-name', contex
t-path: '/app-name', spec-version: '2.5'] Servlet failed with Exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Now my doubt is, is this because of the usage of getServletContext/pageContext? If yes, then what should I use?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I think there should be some more error in the beginning. Can you please share that?

Comment: There will be more caused by errors...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
The logger didn't initialize because of the usage of getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRealPath("..."). This was the 1st error. But I just gave a space and then deleted the space and the error was gone. But every page shows up some error.

Comment: @user1107115 Seems like you have resolved your first issue (i.e deployment), could you update the question with the new error and in which scenario the error is seen.

Comment: NPE should have a stack trace. Using `getRealPath` is a terrible mistake in a portable webapp. If you have the same error on every page, it should be easy to fix: you just have to do it over and over again. What caused you to make the same error on every page?

Comment: Thanks to all those who took the pain to reply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching for the return-NULL-of-getServletContext().getRealPath() behaviour, I found this,

http://ananthkannan.blogspot.in/2009/12/servletcontextgetrealpath-returns-null.html

this did the trick. It was the usage of the getRealPath that deterred the app from running successfully. After enabling the archived getRealPath, its not returning null.